# cURL PHP request and download output

Tags: php, curl

How can I use a CURL command to make a PHP request to output table data to a .csv file and then download that file once it is ready? So far I have:

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['FROMCURL'])){
    if(isset($_GET['table'])){
        $table = $_GET['table'];    
    }

    if($_GET['FROMCURL'] == "test"){
        dump_data($db, $table);
    }
}

function dumpData($db, $table){ 
    $tables = array("x", "y", "z");
    if (in_array($table, $tables)){
        try{
            $dumpData = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
            $dumpData->execute();
            $data = fopen('../$table_'.time().'.csv', 'a');
            while ($row = $dumpData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $csv = array();
                foreach ($row as $key => $val){
                    if($key != 'x_blob' || $key != 'y_blob' || $key != 'z_blob'){
                        $csv[] = $val.',';  
                    }                   
                }
                fputcsv($data, $csv);
            } 
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
    }
}
```

The CURL command I guess is somethnig like

```
curl http://www.website.com/php/tables.php?FROMCURL=test&table=x
```

I'm just not sure how to make it download the file now

Answer (score 0):

You should set the header and *echo* or *print* the content like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sqldump.csv"');

echo $csvdata;
```

And you can download a file with cURL like this:

```
curl -o sqldump.csv "http://url/here"
```

Where '-o' means 'output'

Comment: If i have a .php?val=val&val2=val2  I get an issue with the & sign (table is not recognized as a internal or external command on cmd prompt)

Comment: I forog to add quotation marks around the url. Try this: "http: //url/here"

Answer (score 0):

use curl to get content with get method

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.website.com/php/tables.php?FROMCURL=test&table=x");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch); // return response
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the CURL command is run from Windows.